# Detecting a black box with various text in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I'd like to be able to detect the presence of a black box using opencv in an image. The black box itself may have various types of text and can vary in size. The rest of the image won't be black. Here are a few examples of the type of black boxes I'm referring to:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Obviously, template matching is a no-go, and using feature extraction also seems to be completely wrong since the only real features of the box are the lines of text (which are irrelevant). To my inexperienced computer vision senses it would seem that corner detection would be perhaps be the best approach. However, this still seems somewhat crude and imprecise for something as generic as a rectangle. Can someone suggest a more rigorous method for detection?

Comment: The percentage of black pixels over the whole area should be enough here

Comment: @Miki Which method would best analyze that? It definitely seems like the right approach, but I wasn't sure about the implementation side.

Comment: Don't know much about python, so no code example :D However, you can scan the image and count black pixels, or use countNonZero directly on the image to count non-black pixels. Play with that, post some code  and you'll get an answer sooner